# Conda has two different python binarys (python and python3) with the same version for a single environment. Why?

Tags: python, anaconda, environment, miniconda

As shown below, within the mqst environment, there are two different python binary files: python and python3. But they have the same version, being 3.12. If I do

```
which python
```

I get the python file path. And I will get the python3 file path if I do

```
which python3
```

Does anyone knows why this is the case?
[directory photo containing both python files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAue0.jpg)

This doesn't affect my workflow. But I am just curious.

Comment: Side note: get out of the habit of using `which`. Chances are it doesn't do what you think / want it to do, and there are better and more reliable alternatives. See [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/564341)

Comment: Are you asking why two names or are you asking why two physical files rather than a link?

Comment: Are you asking why it's useful for `python` and `python3` to be pointed to the virtual environments `python3.x` interpreter?